# Splitting a space separated string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

```
String numbers = "5 1 5 1";
```

So, is it:

```
String [] splitNumbers = numbers.split();
```

or:

```
String [] splitNumbers = numbers.split("\s+");
```

Looking for: `["5","1","5","1"]`

Any idea why neither of the `.split` lines will work? I tried reading answers about the regex, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the regex with an additional `\` since `\` denotes the escape character:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbers = "5 1 5 1";
    String[] tokens = numbers.split("\\s+");
    for(String token:tokens){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

So the additional `\` escapes the next `\` which is then treated as the literal `\`.

When using `\\s+` the String will be split on multiple whitespace characters (space, tab, etc).

Answer (score 7):

In your above case `split("\s+");`, you need to escape \ with another backslash, which is:

`split("\\s+");`

Or

`split(" ");` also can do it

**Note** that `split("\\s+");` split **any length** of whitespace including newline(`\n`), tab(`\t`) while  `split(" ");` will split **only single** space.

For example, when you have string separated with two spaces, say "5    1 5 1" ,

using `split("\\s+");` you will get `{"5","1","5","1"}`

while using `split(" ");` you will get `{"5","","1","5","1"}`

Comment: Good note with the different between `"\\s+"` and just `" "`